# Throwing Error while trying to connect with other database connection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

**I want to connect with another database which is on another server so I added a connection name with connection in database.php as following:**

```
'waev' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'waev.in'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', '*********'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', '*********'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '*********'),
            'charset' => 'latin1',
            'collation' => 'latin1_swedish_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

**Then I created a model and named it "central_db.php"**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class central_db extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'waev';
    protected $table = 'usr_waev';
}
```

**And this is my controller(check_subsController.php) where i wrote a query for fetching th data:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\central_db;

class check_subsController extends Controller
{
    public function fetch(Request $request){



        if(\App\central_db::where('device_srno','=',$request->srno)->get()){

            return "ok";
        }

    }
}
```

**But I got this error**

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'waev.usr_waev' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `usr_waev` where
>   `device_srno` = 0426143201394)

please help where i went wrong?

Comment: have you checked if the database is really called 'waev'  on your custom connection ?

Comment: custom connection means where??

Comment: you called it waev

Comment: is it necessary that the name of database and name of connection should be same?

Comment: No it is not neccessarry, but  your error message indicates that you specified in your .env file ( or with ******* if DB_DATABASE does not exists in .env ) that the database is called 'waev'   (Table 'waev.usr_waev' doesn't exist )

Comment: But I am using multiple connections then what should i do. should i change .env every time??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125396/discussion-between-shock-gone-wild-and-sam).